# Are @media Query Overriding the Rulings of my jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, media-queries

I've used jquery inside my angularJS controller to create a dropdown for my navigation bar:

```
$(".fa-bars").click(function() {
  console.log('running ', dropDownDisplayed)
  if (dropDownDisplayed == false) {
    $("#links").css("display", "flex");
    dropDownDisplayed = true;
    console.log('dropdown displayed?', dropDownDisplayed);
  } else if (dropDownDisplayed == true) {
    $("#links").css("display", "none");
    dropDownDisplayed = false;
    console.log('dropdown displayed?', dropDownDisplayed);
  }
});

function menuChecker() {
  if ($scope.loginStatus == true && $(window).width() <= 1024) {
    $("#links").css("top", "240px");
  }
}
```

This is the default css for the dropdown links

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  #links {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 240px;
    height: 3em;
    top: 140px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

however, the value '#links' `top` ruling isn't changing from 140px to 240px when `$scope.loginStatus == true` and the window width is less than 1024. the loginStatus is set to true Why isn't `menuChecker`checking the loginStatus?

note that I'm also using bootstrap, so I don't know if that could be part of the problem.

Comment: *Why isn't menuCheckerchecking the loginStatus?* - who knows? It's not evident that it's even called. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is required. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: The answer in general is: no. The function `css()` applies the properties directly to the elements, as inline styles. So that always overrides any CSS you might have elsewhere (unless you are using !important of course, but that goes without saying). If it doesn't work, then something is going wrong, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

menuChecker was only declared in the document.ready, and never invoked.This has been remedied.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                menuChecker();

                $rootScope.$on("checkMenu", menuChecker);
```